# Java decryption returning blank string

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to retrieve cleartext password of Weblogic admin console which is encrypted in the config.xml file.

I've written the below simple piece of code for this purpose:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    EncryptionService es = SerializedSystemIni.getEncryptionService("$DOMAIN_HOME/Security");
    ClearOrEncryptedService ces = new ClearOrEncryptedService(es);
    System.out.println("Clear text password is : " + ces.decrypt("{3DES}LWmkue/1mmG=")); //the encrypted password which I got from config.xml is being passed as string parameter
}
```

But the problem is although this is working fine in most of the cases, where am able to view the cleartext passwords (for other passwords encrypted in config.xml) but for this particular one am getting a blank string.
Can somebody confirm what exactly is the issue? Am just simply blank without any clue!

Comment: The text `LWmkue/1mmG=` looks like some Base64 encoded bytes.  Try converting the Base64 to bytes and using the actual bytes as your decryption key.

Comment: Partially, `{3DES}` does not look Base64 encoded, the rest would be 8 bytes: 2D69A4B9EFF59A61, to short for a 3DES key, possibly a DES key.

Comment: Are you sure that the password wasn't blank?

Comment: I don't see how anybody can give the answer given the information in the question.

Comment: As I said, there are a few other passwords in the config.xml with same length &{3DES} encryption & for them I am getting a proper cleartext value. Only this one is returning blank string. And the password is not blank, because if I try to login manually by giving a blank password it won't accept.
I will surely try to convert the Base64 encoded bytes to actual bytes (with & without {3DES} & check whether that works.
Another thing I tried by taking the {AES} encrypted key from Weblogic **userconfigfile** but in that case it is returning the encrypted string itself which is given as input

Comment: I tried to decode the encrypted password with sun.misc.BASE64Decoder like this:
'byte[] encryptedPswd = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer("LWmiuK/lCGg=")'
but it is giving output like this:
_Encrypted password is_ : **[B@388993**